# Список словарей из строки

Tags: python

Есть строка вида:

> [{'insp': '4816'}, {'insp': '3252'}, {'insp': '7107'}, {'insp':
>   '5948'}, {'insp': '5257'}, {'insp': '5916'}, {'insp': '1673'},
>   {'insp': '5503'}, {'insp': '6030'}, {'insp': '6439'}, {'insp':
>   '7151'}, {'insp': '2411'}, {'insp': '2208'}, {'insp': '5010'},
>   {'insp': '9978'}, {'insp': '5613'}, {'insp': '2634'}, {'insp':
>   '2308'}, {'insp': '4711'}, {'insp': '5050'}, {'insp': '7721'}]

Как я могу перевести такую строку в список словарей ?

Comment: Откуда вы такую строку получаете?

Comment: Строка похожа на JSON формат, распарсить можно используя функцию [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

Comment: @andreymal неумелая сериализация :)

Comment: @m9_psy собсна в том и проблема, что это не json

Comment: @faoxis а поменять сериализацию на умелую с этим самым json никак?)

Comment: ключи в словаре одинаковые?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#    s = "[{'insp': '4816'}, ... , {'insp': '7721'}]" - исходная строка
s = s.replace('\'','')  #убираем внутренние кавычки
for x in re.findall("\w+: \d+", s): # шаблон - 'строка: число'
    key, value = x.split(': ') 
    print(key, value)
# собрать список словарей не получиться т.к. ключи должны быть уникальны
```

Comment: Можно `list_of_dicts = ast.literal_eval(s)` использовать, вместо строковых манипуляций. Но лучше изменить входной формат на json, чтобы json.loads() работало бы.